# How to extend/Inherit DbSet<TEntity> Class for CustomDbSet using Ef core 8

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working with `Entity Framework Core 8`, implementing the repository pattern with a database-first approach. In my database, I've following tables.

**Branch**

| Id | CityName | ParentBranchId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | null |
| 2 | abc | 1 |

**Product_Identifier**

| Id | BranchId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

**Products**

| Id | Name | OwnedByBranchId | Identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Watermelon | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | watermelo | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Banana | 1 | 2 |

**Product_mapping**

| Id | BranchId | DetailId | IdentifierId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 |

**Description of above tables:**
I have multiple branches in different city and a branch can also have multiple sub branches. I am using *self referencing FK* to achieve this. Now a Product can have different Identifier (like **Watermelon and Banana**) or same Identifier (like **watermelo**) which is not actually new product but it's just an `override` of the Watermelon. Hence, we don't considered it as a new product, now the mapping table is actually mapping the Branch, Product and Identifier. The idea is when I try to get products for `xyz` branch then it should return two products named Watermelon and Banana but when I try to get products for `abc` branch then it should return watermelo and Banana which is based on the product table and it's mapping table.

In short I want to have ability to create overrides of a same product for different branches.

Now to achieve this I have to create a join to get the required data, which I get as follows,

```
public List<Product> GetAll()
{
    var query = context.Product
    .Where(entity => context.ProductMapping
        .Any(entityMapping => entityMapping.DetailId == entity.Id &&
                               entityMapping.BranchId == TenantEntity.Id));
    return query.ToList();
}
```

My objective is to extend or inherit the `DbSet<TEntity>` class, modifying its base behavior to override some fundamental methods. Specifically, when I access Product data using `productDbContext.Product`, I want the returned list to be filtered, including only records where BranchId == TenantEntity.Id (`will get it using dependency injection as I have implemented Multitenancy`) and have a join with **Product_mapping** table as well.

My aim is to integrate this filtering into the base implementation, ensuring that whenever I retrieve Product data from any part of the application with `personDbContext.Product`, it consistently returns filtered results as described earlier.

My primary concern is to avoid adding a <kbd>Where</kbd> condition and <kbd>Join</kbd> everywhere to filter the entity. Additionally, I want to steer clear of implementing a `BaseRepository`, as there's a risk that developers may forget to implement or inherit the BaseRepo when creating new repositories, potentially leading to a break in the desired behavior.

To achieve this, my current approach involves extending the `DbSet<TEntity>` class, overriding its default methods, and adding the necessary filter on the table. However, despite my efforts, when attempting to retrieve data using `productContext.Product`, it returns null instead of the expected IQueryable.

Can you help me identify what I might be missing or misunderstanding in my approach? Is extending the DbSet class the appropriate way to achieve this behavior, or should I explore an alternative approach?

```
[Table("branches")]
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentBranchId { get; set; } // FK Branch.Id
}
```

```
[Table("Product_Identifier")]
public class ProductIdentifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; } // FK Branch.Id
}
```

```
[Table("products")]
public class Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OwnedByBranchId { get; set; } // FK Branch.Id
    public int Identifier { get; set; } // FK ProductIdentifier.Id
}
```

```
[Table("product_mapping")]
public class ProductMapping
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; } // FK Branch.Id
    public int DetailId { get; set; } // FK Products.Id
    public int IdentifierId { get; set; } // FK ProductIdentifier.Id
}
```

```
public class ProductDbContext: DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public ProductDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProductDbContext> dbContextOptions)
       : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }

    public virtual ProductDbSet<Branch> Branch { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductDbSet<ProductIdentifier> ProductIdentifier { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductDbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductDbSet<ProductMapping> ProductMapping { get; set; }
}
```

```
public abstract class ProductDbSet<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly ProductDbContext _context;

    public ProductDbSet(ProductDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override IQueryable<TEntity> AsQueryable()
    {
        // What should I write to return filtered data with join?
    }
}
```

```
public class ProductRepository
{
    private readonly ProductDbContext productDbContext;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public ProductRepository(ProductDbContext productDbContext, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.productDbContext = productDbContext;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public Product GetAll()
    {
        return productDbContext.Product.ToList(); // I want to return filtered Product data (where OwnedByBranchId == TenantEntity.Id)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to. You don't need an CRUD classes named `repository` either. EF is an ORM, a far higher-level abstraction than a low-level "repository". It's job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. ORMs *abstract* single-entity CRUD "repositories", not the other way around. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work and Repository, not a database connection or model.

Comment: What's the *actual* problem you want to solve? Why do you think you need to extend DbSet in any way? You described what you assume the solution will look like, not the problem. `including only records where IsActive == true` that's a job for [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters), eg `modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsActive);`. Or a better table design, using eg temporal tables

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your suggestion, I agree that it's a cleaner way to handle the `IsActive` condition. However, the example code I posted was meant to serve as a basic illustration of my intent. In reality, my requirements involve more complex queries that include necessary joins and additional filtration criteria.
I'm looking for a solution that allows me to extend or inherit the DbSet class to customize its behavior, While global query filters may be suitable for simple scenarios, my use case demands a more dynamic and flexible approach. I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Comment: The entire idea is wrong. That's simply not how EF is meant to work. There's never any reason to inherit from DbSet. `my requirements involve more complex queries` what are those requirements?

Comment: `a more dynamic and flexible approach` inheritance is the opposite of dynamic and flexible. An expression supplied at runtime is *far* more flexible than a hard-coded inheritance relation. You can apply different filters based on conditions, eg `if(whatever) { modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasQueryFilter(....); }`. You can use this eg to implement multitenancy, by returning only the records visible to the current tenant

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have edited my question to explain my use case in detail. Please have a look.

Comment: No matter what your use case is, you won't implement it by inheriting from DbSet. As for what you wrote, it's cause by the misuse of EF. Again (and again, and again) ORMs work with *objects*, not tables, rows and joins. `Product` should have a `Branch` or `Branches` property. Same with Details, `Branch.Products` etc. It's EF's job to generate the queries that retrieve related objects, not yours

Comment: BTW that `GetAll` is essentially useless. Nobody loads an entire table in memory. You're using an ugly *antipattern* here. All the problems are caused by this. I **strongly** suggest looking at the official EF Core tutorials before trying to "fix" or "improve" anything. Check for example the [Many to Many docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many) and how *nothing special* is needed to define the many-to-many relations between Blogs, Posts and Tags. You can even skip the `PostTag` bridge class.

Comment: Agree with Panagiotis here, your DbContext should be a reflection of the database, not a reflection of your business logic.

Comment: Thanks guys , I agree that DbContext should reflect the database, and ORMs work with objects. However, I want the data, as mentioned in the question, using DbSet or some other method. My primary goal is that whenever I write productDbContext.Product, it should always return filtered data.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be concerned with creating your own implementation of `DbSet`, even if you could do it that way. EF Core has a feature called [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) that does this for you. You can configure individual DbSet properties to always apply a filter. For example:

```
public class PersonDbContext: DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public PersonDbContext(DbContextOptions<PersonDbContext> dbContextOptions)
       : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<PersonDataModel> Person { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDataModel>()
            .HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsActive);
    }
}
```

And you would then query as normal. If you wish to ignore the filter, you can also do that by using [IgnoreQueryFilters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#disabling-filters):

```
var allPeople = context.Person
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .ToList()
```

If you are looking to apply much more complex filtering then instead I would suggest other ways to achieve this. For example, you could:

1. Expose your data via a SQL view and query that instead of the base table.
2. Wrap your context in a service class that applies any complex filtering you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question to explain my use case in detail. Can you please take a look at the updated question?